# Back button doesn't dispose App / MainActivity

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, caliburn.micro

Neither my `Application` class nor my `MainActivity` are getting disposed when I click the Back button on my Android phone.

**My problem:**

I cannot figure out if my app is fully closed or just pausing. In both cases

```
protected override void OnSleep() {}
```

is being called.

But as soon as I get it back to the front after pressing the Back-button, the `MainActivity` & Forms `Application` are reinstantiated again and the whole app appears to restart. Whereas by tapping the buttom middle button to minimize it and then bringing it to front again doesnt restart the app and everything is still running and open...

**My question:**

The problem is now, that I have a Application and Activity in memory, which I doesnt use anymore. It is never getting disposed, as far as I can see.

Further more I don't want the app to restart when I click the Back button, how do I solve that issue? I would like it to act exactly like if I have used the minimize button in the middle. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, this is by design. When you are on the root (Main) page, and press the home button, the app just goes to the background, but the main page is still instantiated and in memory. In contrast, when you hit the back button, the app removes the Main page from the navigation stack, thus destroying it. Therefore, the app will need to re-initialize your MainPage (`NavigationPage`), in order to operate.

Comment: But why is both my Application class and my MainActivity initialized, while both old classes are still hold in memory? I have a EventAggregator subscribed to a method on the Application-class and it is called twice (or more times), whenever I press back and maximize the app again. I expect it to dispose both old classes atleast and call the destructor, so I can unsubscribe it from my EventAggregator.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm struggling with. I would assume that all memory allocated by App.xaml.cs would be disposed when the Android back button is pressed. But it's not! How can I manually free all created instances/services when Android back is pressed?